# Variable inside loop inside succes: in ajax call JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I've been working all day on a solution but haven't figured it out. I have a $.ajax call of which I'm looping through  and printing out the values I want. That has been done, my problem is a var array that I have assigned however not being able to manipulate it before displaying it. Inside the success function I start a for loop and assign the var array values, If I don't manipulate them the program continues, however when I add some manipulation it gets stuck. I'm trying to replace \s chars for _ chars but no type of manipulation o the titl[i] has worked. I'm fairly new to JS so there might be something I'm missing, would really aprecciate some insight! cheers.

```
  success: function (x) {
   var titl = [];
   var len = x.query.search.length;

   $('.entries').html("");


   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    titl[i] = x.query.search.title.split(' ').join('_');
    //want to manipulate titl[i] here *************************
     $('.entries').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">' +  x.query.search[i].title + '<br>' + x.query.search[i].snippet + '</div></div>');
```

Comment: `x.query.search.title.split(' ').join('_')` should be `x.query.search[i].title.split(' ').join('_')` (you're missing the `[i]` part).
 Aside from that, in the code shown you add elements to the `titl` array, but never read any values from the array. Are you saying you want the modified values to appear in the HTML you are appending?

Comment: Serious can't believe I overlooked that, all day I was trying different thing... Thank you it is working, and yes I am displying i now, it will be part of a href Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below with comments in it.

```
success: function (x) {
    var titles = [], // Do you need them as an array?
        search = x.query.search,
        searchItem,
        title = '',
        len = search.length,
        $entries = $('.entries'), // Keep the reference in a variable
        html = [];

    // You can just remove all content of entries
    $entries.empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Missing the search index?
        searchItem = search[i];

        // Use push instead and keep title as reference so you can use later on
        title = searchItem.title.split(' ').join('_');
        titles.push(title);

        // Don't append just yet
        html.push('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">');
        html.push(title);
        html.push('<br>');
        html.push(searchItem.snippet);
        html.push('</div></div>');
    }

    // Instead append, just use HTML
    $entries.html(html.join(''));
}
```

Comment: Yeah thank you, there are several entries on the json so those need to be arrays, it turned out that I fogot to assign the [i] index on the titl variable I was working wih, full on went right pass it several time an didn't spot it" Thank you very much anyhow!